# ¿Poner o no poner ; al final de una cadena SQL tiene o podría tener algún efecto?

Tags: sql, lenguaje-agnóstico

Como sabemos, en SQL las instrucciones terminan, ¿o deberían terminar? por un punto y coma `;`.

O sea:

```
SELECT persona_id, persona_nom FROM persona;
```

Pero resulta que en los lenguajes de programación, se escribe con mucha frecuencia de esta forma:

**Forma A:**

```
$SQL="SELECT persona_id, persona_nom FROM persona";
```

Aquí el punto y coma al final es para indicar el final de *esa línea* en el lenguaje de programación, no de la instrucción SQL, la cual se enviará al manejador de BD **sin el punto y coma**.

Generalmente la instrucción SQL funciona **sin el punto y coma de ella**.

En mi caso yo trato de escribir así:

**Forma B:**

```
$SQL="SELECT persona_id, persona_nom FROM persona;";
```

Aquí sólo se enviará al manejador de la BD el punto y coma **dentro** de las comillas, mientras que el punto y coma final indicará un final de línea en el lenguaje de programación.

Mi pregunta es si podría tener algún resultado inesperado o simplemente el programa podría fallar en algunos casos cuando usamos la **forma A**.

Un escenario en el que (pienso), podría ser problemático, sería en el hipotético caso de ejecutar, en llamadas sucesivas, instrucciones SQL normales y Stored Procedures o funciones creadas por el mismo usuario.

Comment: Hablas de SQL con lenguajes de Programación, virtualmente no tienen ningún efecto el poner o no `;` eso es más cuando tienes procedimientos almacenados, triggers, o archivos SQL con múltiples sentencias que necesitan ser separadas por `;`

Comment: @Lixus Correcto, hablo de SQL en lenguajes de programación, desde los cuales puedes llamar también procedimientos almacenados.

Comment: No termino de entender la pregunta. En general las clases de los lenguajes se ocupan de escapar las sentencias sql, entonces no necesitas mandar los ;. Entonces la pregunta a que apunta? Si no lo hicieran los objetos propios de las clases, seguramente habria muchos bugs ya detectados. Uno no deberia preocuparse por esas cosas.

Comment: @gbianchi Lo que dices: _En general las clases de los lenguajes se ocupan de escapar las sentencias sql_, no me queda claro, no me consta y si hubiera alguna forma de probarlo sería útil e interesante. Y en cuanto a _preocuparse_ por esas cosas... bueno puede ser un defecto de perfeccionismo... pero total, se trata de un punto y coma al final, tampoco es tanto ¿no?

Comment: si, puedes mirarlo revisando la definicion de las clases y los codigos fuentes. Tambien puedes ver que si las sentencias no estuvieran escapadas automaticamente, los sql nos fallarian a todos y estariamos todos poniendo los ;... Ademas tu forma A tiene un defecto gravisimo, no todos los lenguajes terminan sus instrucciones con ;, por lo tanto ya tu pregunta dejo de ser totalmente agnostica.

Comment: @gbianchi Considero que lo del `;  ` agnóstico es mucho menos relevante. En cuanto al punto y coma de SQL. Ya hay una respuesta que indica que para SQL Server en versiones posteriores a la 2016 el omitirlo es obsoleto y por tanto, una mala practica. Y otra dice que en MySQL, al omitirlo, dejas al manejador _esperando_, lo cual es por lo menos _mala educación_ por parte de un programador. De todos modos, quisiera ver documentado en alguna parte lo que dices, de que los lenguajes de programación ponen el `;` que omitimos en el caso de SQL. Si lo probamos con multiquery casi seguro que falla.

Comment: pero con multiquery es otro problema! si yo escribo varias querys y no las escapo, es lo mismo que las escribiera mal. y todo lo que te dijeron, es dentro de las bases de datos, no en las conexiones externas y los querys ejecutados desde afuera. Es muy diferente el planteo, creo que estas confundiendo el concepto de las querys dentro del motor mismo, con ejecutar querys desde afuera para recibir datos.

Comment: @gbianchi No es diferente, ya que las consultas que generas desde cualquier lenguaje son enviadas al manejador de la BD, no son enviadas _al aire_ . En ese sentido no hay ninguna diferencia.

Comment: No,al aire no. A una capa intermedia

Comment: por ejemplo la clase sqlcommand envia a una conexion a SQL server, la query como un prepare statement, no como una query pura. Entonces el ; que podes agregar al final no tiene ningun sentido. mira aca https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265192/get-the-generated-sql-statement-from-a-sqlcommand-object

Comment: Me pregunto: si quiero poner yo mismo el punto y coma, y no delegarlo a la capa intermedia, ¿hay algún problema?. [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/ESBTR/esscmd_syntax_semicolon.html) también recomienda terminar con `; `

Comment: No hay ningun problema,eso tratamos de decir. El driver que uses en tu aplicación para comunicarte con la base de datos es suficientemente inteligente para detectar eso. A parte, que tampoco pasaría nada por tener dos puntos y coma consecutivos

Comment: ninguno, pero las recomendaciones de las bases de datos son para trabajar dentro de ellas, no para los querys que uno manda. e igual, son recomendaciones...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No se que motor de base de datos ocupas actualmente, pero en SQL Server

Hasta la versión 2012, tu puedes crear transacciones sin el punto y coma final, no afecta en su funcionamiento. Sin embargo, en nuevas versiones (2016) esto quedo obsoleto y ahora es *OBLIGATORIO* terminar todo tipo de transacción sql con `;`.

En [esta](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016) pagina puedes ver las funciones y sentencias obsoletas con sql server 2016 .

> Funcion obsoleta : No terminar instrucciones de Transact-SQL con un
>   punto y coma.
>
> Funcion de reemplazo : declaraciones finales de Transact-SQL con un
>   punto y coma (;).

Comment: Suelo usar MySQL. Pensé que podía dar algún problema si usamos funciones del tipo multiquery, o si se combinan, en llamadas consecutivas, instrucciones SQL con Stored Procedures o con funciones personalizadas.

Comment: creo que podrias estar atento a documentos nuevos de mysql, tal como sql server algunas cosas las deprecaron y cambiaron, quizas en algun momento tambien obligen a ocupar el punto y coma en cada transaccion..

Comment: ohhh, al leer la respuesta creí que era obsoleto **usar el ;**, pero lo que parece ser obsoleto es **no usarlo**. ¿Estoy en lo cierto o es un error de apreciación?

Comment: exacto!, al menos en sql server es obsoleto desde la version 2016. :D

Comment: Entonces podemos concluir que la **forma B**, al menos de cara SQL Server, es la recomendada. No sé si tu respuesta no es del todo clara o al leer entre obsoleto no obsoleto y la respuesta de @Rostan, que dice lo contrario de la tuya, me he confundido. De todos modos cuando dices: _pero luego en versiones posteriores esto se dejo como obsoleto_, si indicas explícitamente _qué es "esto"_, quedaría más clara. Perdona la insistencia.

Comment: voy a modificarla para que se entienda bien, pero ojo, yo deje un link de la pagina oficial en donde te explican eso, no es que yo lo haya invetado

Comment: Pero esto es en la BD o desde un lenguaje??? o sea si en C# en un objeto connection escribo la query "select * from tabla", no funciona?

Comment: Es en la base de datos, no he trabajado aun con c# y sql 2016, pero tal como dice en la documentacion, para realizar transacciones sql DEBE IR el punto y coma final. Por favor lee el documento

Comment: @gbianchi Lee bien la pregunta. En ningún momento se ha dicho que _no funciona_ si se omite el `;   `al final. La cuestión no es si funciona a no, sino las consecuencias que podría tener el omitirlo. Por lo afirmado en esta respuesta, al menos para SQL Server 2016+  omitirlo sería una **mala práctica**. Además, no veo por qué no se podría poner, como se indica en la **forma B** de la pregunta. No entiendo tu cerrazón en ese sentido. Los `;  `son _gratis_ en el teclado, no te van a cobrar por ponerlos.

Comment: La respuesta no es correcta del todo. SQL Server lleva años diciendo que el punto y coma está obsoleto, por lo menos desde la [versión 2012](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.110).aspx), pero ellos mismos siguen generando sentencias sin punto y coma en SSMS, así que es difícil tomarlos en serio.

Comment: @sstan me parece valido tu -1, sin embargo cuando uno utiliza herramientas que cuentan con documentación lo correcto seria regirse a lo que la documentación dice, por eso expuse esta respuesta. Tomar enserio o no a una herramienta y sus documentos, va en cada uno. Saludos!

Comment: @sioesi: En realidad estoy de acuerdo contigo en cuanto a tomar en serio la doc, y yo mismo trato de usar el punto y coma lo mas que puedo, aunque es frustrante que SSMS mismo me las quita. Pero, disculpa si no fui claro, la razón del -1 es porque no es cierto que el no usar el punto y coma ha sido marcado obsoleto desde 2016 (es desde 2012 por lo menos), ni tampoco es cierto que ahora es obligatorio usar el punto y coma. En realidad, entre 2012 y 2016 no hubo cambio en esto. Si puedes ajustar ese párrafo será apreciado. Y gracias por dejarme el comentario para poder aclarar.

Answer (score 3):

En el caso de PostgreSQL si ejecutas una consulta desde la consola de comandos, la consulta no se ejecuta hasta que pongas el punto y coma para indicar el final de la consulta.

Por otro lado si escribes consultas dentro de PgAdmin puedes o no utilizar el punto y coma y las dos formas son igualmente válidas.

Answer (score 2):

tu respuesta a esto ***:¿Poner o no poner ; al final de una cadena SQL tiene o podría tener algún efecto?*** es **SI** los lenguajes de programación agregan automaticamente el punto y coma, como los gestores de datos un ejemplo de ellos **`PhPMyAdmin, MySqlWorkBench, PhPgAdmin  ,PgAmin3`** (que los he manejado) tambien lo hacen; basta con ejecutar estas instrucciones directamente con el motor y hasta no leer el `;` seguira esperando la instruccion en la imagen te colocare el ejemplo

[image: imagen ejemplo]

Comment: Correcto... había leído que MySQL _se queda esperando_ si no escribes el `;  ` al final, lo cual sería, por decirlo de alguna manera, _mala educación por parte del programador_ por no decir que es una mala práctica omitir el punto y coma. Fue precisamente al leer eso que empecé a poner un punto y coma **dentro de las comillas** cuando creo instrucciones SQL en PHP o en Java.

Comment: queda de parte del programador y volvemos a que esto deberia ser parte de las buenas practicas de desarrollo

Answer (score 2):

> Un escenario en el que (pienso), podría ser problemático, sería en el hipotético caso de ejecutar, en llamadas sucesivas, instrucciones SQL normales y Stored Procedures o funciones creadas por el mismo usuario.

La clave está en **sucesivas**. Las sentencias se enviarán a la base de datos de una en una, con lo que el `;` no es necesario en ningun caso.

Por otro lado,cualquier ORM moderno (o conectores de bases de datos) está de sobra capacitado para gestionar todas estas cuestiones.

Comment: No diría _en ningún caso_. Un ejemplo típico es el de [multiquery](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php). Y como ha respondido @sioesi omitir el punto y coma se considera una práctica obsoleta a partir de SQL Server 2016.

Comment: @A.Cedano del enlace que pones: _Ejecuta una o múltiples consultas concatenadas por puntos y comas._ Obviamente si tu estás mandando mas de una consulta, debes separarlos por ;

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que tu planteas en tu pregunta son varias queries _consecutivas_

Comment: A.Cedano y por último, lo que enlaza @sioesi se refiere al SQL Server, no a las consultas **desde una aplicación**

Comment: Las consultas que se generan en la aplicación van a parar al manejador de bases de datos ¿o no?.  No veo por qué haces diferencia.

Comment: Pues es bastante evidente que hay diferencia. Las consultas que se hacen desde una aplicación pasan por una capa intermedia (un conector de bases de datos,odb,orm...) que sanean la query y si es necesario añadirian ese punto y coma final

Comment: Hablo principalmente de .Net que es lo que domino, pero imagino que en lenguajes como java es similar

Answer (score 1):

El uso o no uso del ";" no respresenta un riesgo. Ambas formas son válidas, hasta donde conozco el uso del mismo se recomendó desde las primeras versiones de SQL, buscando preparar a los programadores para una posible implementación y obligación, cosa que al parecer en la versión SQL 2016 se declara como obsoleta. No quita la posibilidad de que su uso en el futuro sea obligatorio como en lenguajes de programación tales como Java. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En resumen: **No** hay diferencia entre las dos formas que presentaste porque por lo general ese punto y coma se esta poniendo por implicitamente. Haciendo que la forma B dos resulte en :

```
SELECT persona_id, persona_nom FROM persona;;
```

Ahora dependiendo de lo que estés haciendo (y por cultura general) te recomiendo que leas sobre Inyección SQL.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL

Comment: Gracias, pero la pregunta es relativa a lo que se envía a la BD. En ese sentido el punto y coma que va fuera (forma B), no se envía de ningún modo a la BD, pues pertenece al lenguaje de programación y sirve para indicar que _esa_ línea ha terminado. Sobre la Inyección SQL, [he contribuido en algo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967)  a la pregunta principal sobre ese tema aquí en esSO, es decir, que no desconozco el asunto.

Answer (score 0):

El punto  y coma también sirve en  SQL cuando se tiene muchas instrucciones en un solo lote (triggers, procedimientos almacenados, etc) pero puedes sustituirlo con BEGIN - END que es lo mismo que {} en cualquier otro lenguaje de programación