# No me funciona fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Soy estudiante y en una de mis video clases me doy cuenta que mi codigo se rompia al usar la funcion fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) verifique la sintaxis de mi codigo una y otra vez hasta he llegado a hacerlo practicamente desde el inicio y aun no puedo resolver el problema.

```
 <?php include_once 'includes/templates/header.php'; ?>

    <section class="seccion contenedor">
          <h2>Calendario de Eventos</h2>

          <?php
              try {
                require_once('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');
                $sql = 'SELECT* FROM `eventos`;';
                $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
              } catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
              }
           ?>

           <?php while($eventos = $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) { ?>

             <pre><?php var_dump($eventos); ?></pre>

           <?php } ?>

    </section>
```

Ese seria el codigo que deberia funcionar, cuando guardo los cambios y recargo el navegador solo carga la parte del "header.php" y el titulo "Calendario de Eventos" y el "footer.php" no aparece. Es como si no estuviera.
De hecho

```
 <?php include_once 'includes/templates/header.php'; ?>

    <section class="seccion contenedor">
          <h2>Calendario de Eventos</h2>

          <?php
              try {
                require_once('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');
                $sql = 'SELECT* FROM `eventos`;';
                $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
              } catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
              }
           ?>

           <?php while($eventos = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) { ?>

             <pre><?php var_dump($eventos); ?></pre>

           <?php } ?>

    </section>
```

Si cambio la funcion antes mencionada por fetch_assoc() funciona correctamente sin problemas. El problema es que para continuar con la video clase tengo que usar fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC). Caso contrario no obtengo los resultados que deberia obtener.

Comment: El [Manual dice](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) que  `fetch_all` está **_disponible sólo con [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqlnd.php)_**. Si no lo tienes instalado no te funcionará. Para salir de dudas, ejecuta esta prueba: `$mysqlnd = function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all'); if ($mysqlnd) {
    echo 'mysqlnd activado!';
}else{ echo 'Lo siento, mysqlnd no está activado';}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando esa función te saca error significa que es la consulta la que está mal hecha ya que al estar mal hecha no devuelve lo que espera realmente el `fetch_all()`, en tu línea de `$sql` veo que tienes un ; dentro de el `string` de tu consulta eso puede ser lo que la está rompiendo prueba haciendola de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM eventos";
```

Algo más, si estás usando PDO tengo entendido que la función es de la siguiente manera `fetchAll()`

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

**SOLUCIONADO**

Después de depurar un `error 500` que salia en la `consola` y en el `network` se tomó la desicion de cambiar de servidor (de mamp a xampp) y esto fue suficiente para lograr el resultado esperado puesto a que en cuanto a código no había ningún error

Comment: Intente corregir como sugeria la respuesta pero aun asi sigo teniendo el error. Vale decir que he controlado linea por linea y tengo el codigo igual que mi instructor aun asi no consigo que funcione.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código puede no funcionar por dos motivos.

### 1er motivo: Uso equivocado de la función

El [Manual dice bien claro lo siguiente](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php):

> Dado que `mysqli_fetch_all()` **devuelve todas las filas en un array en
>   un solo paso**, puede consumir más memoria que otras funciones
>   similares tales como `mysqli_fetch_array()`, que sólo devuelve una
>   fila cada vez a partir del resultado. Por tanto, si se necesita
>   recorrer un resultado, será necesario un bucle que minimice el impacto
>   en rendimiento. Por esta razón, se aconseja que sólo se use
>   `mysqli_fetch_all()` en aquellas situaciones en que el resultado se
>   tenga que enviar a otra capa o nivel para que lo procese.

O sea, **cuando usas `fetch_all` no tienes que leer el resultado en un bucle... ¡ya tienes todo el resultado!**

Entonces:

```
$eventos=mysqli_fetch_all($resultado,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
var_dump($eventos);
```

Todo el resultado ya está en `$eventos,` eso es lo que hace `fetch_all`.

---

### 2do motivo: No tienes el driver `mysqlnd`

Si corriges lo dicho antes y no funciona, ten en cuenta que el [Manual dice](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) que  `fetch_all` está

> disponible sólo con
>   [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqlnd.php).

Si no lo tienes instalado no te funcionará.

Para salir de dudas, ejecuta esta prueba:

```
$mysqlnd = function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all'); 

if ($mysqlnd) 
{
    echo 'mysqlnd activado!'; 

}else{ 

    echo 'Lo siento, mysqlnd no está activado';

}
```

---

### La solución que podría ser más óptima

Tomando en cuenta lo anterior, la solución más óptima sería un código que no dependa del driver `mysqlnd` y que además no afecte al rendimiento, es decir, el código como lo tienes en la segunda parte de tu pregunta, **corrigiendo el error ortográfico del `SELECT*`**:

```
<section class="seccion contenedor">
      <h2>Calendario de Eventos</h2>

      <?php
          try {
            require_once('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `eventos`;';
            $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
          } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
          }
       ?>

       <?php while($eventos = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) { ?>

         <pre><?php var_dump($eventos); ?></pre>

       <?php } ?>

</section>
```

Comment: Efectivamente era un problema de driver mysqlnd se pudo solucionar cambiando de servidor.

Comment: @MaxiiPerez de todos modos, estás usando mal `fetch_all`  si has dejado el código como lo tenías, no tiene ningún sentido usar `fetch_all` y luego leer los resultados dentro de un bucle, es más bien un contra sentido... es usar `fecht_all` por evitar hacer algo que luego haces. Lee la nota del Manual que puse en mi respuesta. `fetch_all` es para tener los resultados enteros.

Comment: Solo es parte de un ejercicio soy estudiante, no lo voy a aplicar a un codigo real. Todo es con fines de aprendizaje y entendimiento.

Comment: Entiendo @MaxiiPerez pero los **problemas reales del código** son los que expongo aquí, el código no da error porque tengas un `;` dentro de las comillas, al respecto puedes ver esta pregunta: [¿Poner o no poner ; al final de una cadena SQL tiene o podría tener algún efecto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78847/29967) y si pones `;` en el nuevo código verás que funciona. Daba error porque se cumplía el 2º motivo expuesto... al cambiar a una instalación que tenía el driver `mysqlnd` te funcionó. En cuanto al 1er motivo, es importante tomarlo en cuenta, pues afecta al rendimiento del código.

Comment: Creo que voy pillando mejor lo que me dices, muchas gracias por tu tiempo y consejos voy a tenerlo en cuenta.