# PHP array recorrerlo

Tags: php, array, php7

tengo un **problema** con los `array` en `PHP` y no sera por no mirar ejemplos la verdad, pero aun sigo sin comprender su naturaleza, sea porque estoy acostumbrado a `java` o no puedo decir porque. Pongo un ejemplo:

**Creo mi** `array`

```
$mensajes = array();
```

Bueno eso es un `array`, sin problemas, un objeto que contiene una **coleccion de otros objetos** (*elementos*) .

Si yo tengo ahora un **bucle** con el que **rellenar** ese `array`, con la intencion de hacerlo `array` **asociativo**, pues yo haria lo siguiente:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "ID MENSAJE = " . $row['mensaje_id']. "<br>";
    echo "TITULO MENSAJE = " . $row['mensaje_titulo']. "<br>";
    echo "MENSAJE CONTENIDO = " . $row['mensaje_contenido']. "<br>";
    echo "MENSAJE CREATEAT " . $row['mensaje_createAt']. "<br>";
    echo "MENSAJE CREADOR = " . $row['mensaje_creador']. "<br>";
    echo "MENSAJE URL IMG = " . $row['mensaje_url_img']. "<br>";
    echo "ETIQUETA ID = " . $row['etiquetas_ids']. "<br>";
    echo "ETIQUETA NOMBRE = " . $row['etiquetas_nombres']. "<br>";
    echo "------------------ <br>";

    //$etiquetas = explode('|',$row['etiquetas_nombres']);
    $mensajes['id'] = $row['mensaje_id'];
    $mensajes['titulo'] = $row['mensaje_titulo'];
    $mensajes['contenido'] = $row['mensaje_contenido'];
    $mensajes['createAt'] = $row['mensaje_createAt'];
    $mensajes['creador'] = $row['mensaje_creador'];
    $mensajes['url_img'] = $row['mensaje_url_img'];
}
```

Como se puede apreciar, es un bucle `while` que por cada **iteracion** del `$result` voy a **almacenar** su contenido en mi variable `$row`, esta tendra en **cada iteracion** un`array` **cargado de diferentes valores**.

Entonces digo: **voy a guardar las iteraciones que almaceno en $row separandolas por sus atributos**(*id,titulo,contenido,createAt,..*)

**Una vez acabe el bucle**, en teoria, debo tener la variable `$mensajes` cargada de todos esos datos

Bueno, mi siguiente paso es comprobar que este bien el **array** `$mensajes` asi que hago esto:

```
foreach ($mensajes as $key ) {
    echo $key['id'];
    echo $key['titulo'];
    echo $key['contenido'];
    echo $key['createAt'];
    echo $key['creador'];
    echo $key['url_img'];
}
```

Por lo visto `PHP` **NO** me lo permite, me dice `Illegal string offset 'id'` y asi con **todos** los **atributos**.

Entonces pruebo con lo siguiente:

```
foreach ($mensajes as $key ) {
    echo $key;
}
```

Esto me muestra:

```
141titulo mensaje 2contenido mensaje 22019-04-25 20:29:1515cc1fc7ba0c713.37620569.png
```

Es decir, **uno de los muchos $row que deberia de tener almacenado**, entonces eso es lo que me confunde, el que no almacene todos los datos que en el **bucle** le voy **asignando**. Lo que parece es que esta **sobreescribiendo** el valor anterior por cada iteracion

Comment: Creo que tu problema está cuando le asignas los valores a tu array `mensajes` me parece que estás sobreescribiendo el valor anterior, creo que tu lógica debería ser tener un arreglo de arreglos. Para ello te recomiendo que asignes así: `$mensajes[] = array( 'id' => $row['mensaje_id'],  'titulo' => $row['mensaje_titulo'], ...)` y así

Comment: Es como dice @GermanAlzate. Incluso, puedes simplificar el código si quieres, ya que no es obligatorio meter cada valor a mano en el array. Puedes hacer algo así dentro del `while`: **`$mensajes[]=$row;`**  y ya está. Para hacer eso, conviene escribir *código específico*, o sea, que escribas un `SELECT` donde explicites las columnas, o sea, en vez de `SELECT *`, escribir: `SELECT col1, col2, colN...` (eso se debería hacer siempre), y usar `mysqli_fetch_assoc` en vez de `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Comment: @A.Cedano como nota, si las columnas son siempre las mismas, select * y select col1, col2, etc dan lo mismo.. sabias no?

Comment: Dicho sea de paso, también podría hacer `$mensajes = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` y listo...

Comment: @gbianchi sí claro, pero por ser disciplinado creo que siempre se debería escribir cada columna de forma explícita en un `SELECT`, aun cuando se necesiten todas.

Comment: @A.Cedano perfecto!

Comment: Muchas veces no se usan columnas de las consultas y estaran alli en tu memoria sin hacer nada

Comment: @Marcos, sólo que `fetch_all` [no funciona si no tiene el driver `mysqlnd` instalado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/106746/29967) y no se recomienda cuando se esperan muchos resultados.

Comment: @A.Cedano, correcto, es un detalle a tener en cuenta pero sumado a lo ya comentado, sería los mas simple y optimo.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, poco a poco voy entendiendo mejor la cosa. Ahora, en relacion a esto me puse a hacer lo siguiente: ya que tengo mi `array` cargado de los datos necesarios quise **dividir mejor** la parte de las `etiquetas` añadiendo un `array` dentro de otro `array` , quedando asi la cosa:

Comment: $mensajes[] = [
       'id' => $row['mensaje_id'],
       'titulo' => $row['mensaje_titulo'],
       'contenido' => $row['mensaje_contenido'],
       'createAt' => $row['mensaje_createAt'],
       'creador' => $row['mensaje_creador'],
       'url_img' =>  $row['mensaje_url_img'],
       'etiquetas'=> array(
        'ids'=> explode('|', $row['etiquetas_ids']),
           'nombres'=> explode('|', $row['etiquetas_nombres'])

       )
      ];

Comment: Hice uso de la funcion `explode()` para tener dentro de `etiquetas` dos atributos : `ids` y `nombres`, pero no parece buena idea, pues php no me permite displayearlo de esta forma : `echo $key['etiquetas']['etiquetas_ids'] . "<br>";
   echo $key['etiquetas']['etiquetas_nombres'] . "<br>";`

Answer (score 1):

Como tu mismo comentas:

> Lo que parece es que esta sobreescribiendo el valor anterior por cada iteracion

#### Solución:

La forma correcta para agregar datos a un arreglo en `PHP` es la siguiente:

```
$mensajes = []; // Definimos el arreglo
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  // Agregamos una nueva posicion al arreglo
  $mensajes[] = [
    'id' => $row['mensaje_id'],
    'titulo' => $row['mensaje_titulo'],
    'contenido' => $row['mensaje_contenido'],
    'createAt' => $row['mensaje_createAt'],
    'creador' => $row['mensaje_creador'],
    'url_img' => $row['mensaje_url_img'],
  ];
}
```

#### Extras:

Sino necesitaras cambiar el nombre de los datos (`eg: mensaje_id por id, etc.`) podrías simplemente hacer:

- [`mysqli_fetch_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

  ```
  $mensajes = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  ```
- Si no tuvieras disponible `mysqli_fetch_all`, entonces:

  ```
  $mensajes = [];
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       $mensajes[] = $row;
  }
  ```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta (no sé por qué te votaron negativamente). Aunque, deberías explicar por qué es la forma correcta. Si lees la pregunta el OP anda confundido con el asunto de los arrays.

Comment: Pero cometiste un desliz en tu **Extras**. Si se usa `mysqli_fetch_all` ya en el resultado tiene un array con los datos y no necesita usar el `while`. Es decir que aquí: `$mensajes = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` ya `$mensajes` es un array con los datos.

Comment: Oh sí, no me fijé en el comentario. Al ver el código de seguido se interpreta como que después del `fetch_all` va el `while`. Eso puede confundir, a mi modo de ver.

Comment: @A.Cedano, lista la v3 :P

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar algo como esto para recorrer tu arreglo

```
foreach ($mensajes as $key => $value) {
    dump($key.' '.$value);
}
```